Task<HttpClient>' does not contain a definition for 'GetFromJsonAsync'
I created a c# class library for my project and created a class called GetHttpClient.cs
when i use GetPublicHttpClient() function there is no error but when use GetPrivateHttpClient()
the following error is displayed:(Task' does not contain a definition for 'GetFromJsonAsync' and the best extension method overload 'HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(HttpClient, string?, CancellationToken)' requires a receiver of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient')
I installed all the required packages such as Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0"
my code is :
using BaseLibrary.DTOs;

namespace ClientLibrary.Helpers
{
public class GetHttpClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, LocalStorageService localStorageService)
{
private const string HeaderKey = "Authorization";

        public async Task<HttpClient> GetPrivateHttpClient()
        {
            var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SystemApiClient");
            var stringToken = await localStorageService.GetToken();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToken)) return client;
    
            var deserializeToken = Serializations.DeserializeJsonString<UserSession>(stringToken);
            if (deserializeToken == null) return client;
    
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", deserializeToken.Token);
            return client;
        }
    
        public HttpClient GetPublicHttpClient()
        {
            var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SystemApiClient");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove(HeaderKey);
            return client;
        }
    
    }

}

and UserAccountService.cs Code is
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using BaseLibrary.DTOs;
using BaseLibrary.Responses;
using ClientLibrary.Helpers;
using ClientLibrary.Services.Contracts;

namespace ClientLibrary.Services.Implementations
{
public class UserAccountService(GetHttpClient getHttpClient) : IUserAccountService
{
public const string AuthUrl = "api/authentication";
public async Task<GeneralResponse> CreateAsync(Register user)
{
var httpClient = getHttpClient.GetPublicHttpClient();
var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{AuthUrl}/register", user);
if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return new GeneralResponse(false, "Error occurred");

            return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<GeneralResponse>()!;
        }
    
        public async Task<LoginResponse> SignInAsync(Login user)
        {
            var httpClient = getHttpClient.GetPublicHttpClient();
            var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{AuthUrl}/login", user);
            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return new LoginResponse(false, "Error occurred");
    
            return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResponse>()!;
        }
    
        public Task<LoginResponse> RefreshTokenAsync(RefreshToken token)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    
        public async Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetWeatherForecast()
        {
            var httpClient = getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
            var result = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("api/weatherforecast");
          
            return result!;
        }
    }

}


i read several documents but i could not solve the problem

hello my friend you have add an await in first line of GetWeatherForecast method:
var httpClient = await getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
